# Can't compile Moonlight application in MonoDevelop

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, moonlight

I am trying to build Moonlight application using MonoDevelop 2.8 and Mono 2.10.5 on Mac OS X but it fails to compile:

```
Error: Framework 'Moonlight / Silverlight 3.0' not installed. (MoonlightTest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Moonlight addin on Mac is somewhat limited. It uses Silverlight to run the apps, since there is no Moonlight plugin for Mac has been released, but it uses the Moonlight SDK assemblies to compile, since the Silverlight SDK assemblies cannot be redistributed. Unfortunately the only SDK package released for Moonlight was 2.0 - Moonlight skipped 3.0 and assemblies for 4.0 exist but were never released as an SDK.

Comment: So, there is no way to develop SL application on Mac?

Comment: Not right now without some manual work fo fix stuff up, sorry.