# Compiling moonlight application on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, moonlight

I'm using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) 2.8.5 and I'm trying to compile a moonlight application, but it fails. I created a brand new Moonlight Application Project and tried to compile it, but it fails with the following error.

```
Error: Framework 'Moonlight / Silverlight 4.0' not installed. (MoonlightTest)
```

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691746/cant-compile-moonlight-application-in-monodevelop) from October 2011 [one of the developers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116899/mhutch) of MonoDevelop states that is not possible to do this without some major hassle.

1. Is this still true with the new version(s) of MonoDevelop out?
2. If so, how can I compile Moonlight Application Projects in MonoDevelop if I'm willing to go through some hassle?

Comment: You have to persuade monodevelop that the moonlight 4 framework is supported and what compilers and framework paths it needs, You need to add a new project type I think.

Comment: hmm. there is a moonlight project type that I can create from the menues, but it does not compile.

Comment: Was about to ask the same question, but added a bounty instead. Background: I've got a silverlight app developed by someone using Windows, and now I've been tasked to fix something in it. I'm on Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

Comment: nice! hopefully catches some more attention now. Personally I would just love it for those quick prototypes.

Comment: Have you tried to build the solution with xbuild?

Comment: @IanNorton no, I havn't. Should produce the same result?

Comment: No bounty awarded this time. Too bad, the points are lost =(

Comment: @JoelPurra you can still award them manually to Mike if you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of "psychic debugging" but I've run into it a lot in linux and imagine you might have the same problem happening on OS X. Is the compiler that Monodevelop is looking for exactly the same as the version you installed? It might be something as simple as the folder being called Moonlight1.3 vs Moonlight1.3.1. Look at the build output and see what version it is looking for then look in your applications folder (via terminal the app folder in the finder might hide the info) and check that they are the same.

Comment: This might help, and I will try it for the next round of testing. (It's not what I was looking for for the bounty though, but thanks!)

Comment: @Joel Purra nice, let us know